# Is it possible to check which nodes banned my node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, p2p

I can ban peers with `setban` and check banned peers with `listbanned` in Bitcoin Core. Can I check which peers banned me?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35536/how-can-i-get-my-peers-ban-score-for-my-node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot know this. But in general, since you're a normal, honest, node presumably, the most likely answer is "none".